# Doctrine2 - is there a pre-selection hook?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm developing a ws with Symfony2 / Doctrine2, and I'm trying to hook into Doctrine2 lifecycle and trigger a function before any SELECT action - but without any luck. Basically, i'd like to dynamically manipulate the selection queries adding limit/offset when certain parameters are found in the request, but it seems that [Doctrine2 hooks](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events) concern only insert, delete and update actions. Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

U have to use [Doctrine Filter](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html)

Doctrine 2.2 features a filter system that allows the developer to add SQL to the conditional clauses of queries, regardless the place where the SQL is generated (e.g. from a DQL query, or by loading associated entities).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Sina. The filter system work great, but unfortunately you can't add a limit clause since everything you can do is adding where clauses (preceded by a boolean operator, which breaks query execution because of a syntax error with limit). I haven't found solutions for this.

Comment: limiting rows is really something that related to business logic ! for example its related to pagination of a specific page ... not related to overall queries for that entity in anywhere !

Answer (score 0):

A way to deal with this would be to register a custom event that is dispatched before a select. You have already referenced the source that shows examples of how to do it.

Comment: Thankyou lobostome! The only problem with your approach is that i would have to dispatch the event manually everytime a selection is performed, since there is apparently no doctrine event dispatched before/after a selection.