# Is there a way to set a Doctrine Event Listener that limits every entity query to a specific field id?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, listeners

Setting [Doctrine Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) for Persisting and Updating entities is an extremely useful feature. But that appears to be limited to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statements. What about `SELECT` queries?

Let's say I have a hosted CMS with a shared database where every record has a `siteId` denoting that a record belongs to a certain site. When I search for records (entities) to display on a given site, I need to limit the results to only records for the specific `siteId`. I could manually limit every single query in my code, but that has the potential for forgetting (which could be a security issue). So I am considering making this automatic for every single query (I may need to override in some instances).

So can you manipulate the DQL or QueryBuilder in some sort of `preSelect` Event Listener so that it makes sure that we always limit by the siteId?

And if so, ideally we could overwrite this in system administrative interfaces where we want to find all records regardless of siteId.

Is this possible? Is this a bad idea? Does this smell like Rosemary?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `Doctrine Filters`.

[Doctrine2 - is there a pre-selection hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14943619/doctrine2-is-there-a-pre-selection-hook)

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html

> Doctrine 2.2 features a filter system that allows the developer to add
>   SQL to the conditional clauses of queries, regardless the place where
>   the SQL is generated (e.g. from a DQL query, or by loading associated
>   entities).
>
> The filter functionality works on SQL level. Whether a SQL query is
>   generated in a Persister, during lazy loading, in extra lazy
>   collections or from DQL. Each time the system iterates over all the
>   enabled filters, adding a new SQL part as a filter returns.
>
> By adding SQL to the conditional clauses of queries, the filter system
>   filters out rows belonging to the entities at the level of the SQL
>   result set. This means that the filtered entities are never hydrated
>   (which can be expensive).

Comment: It says it filters at the SQL level, does that mean it actually adds the filter to the SQL query that is executed? For some reason in the back of my mind, I thought I read somewhere to be aware because this filters AFTER the results are returned...

Comment: It seems that you are correct. What I get from docs is that filters are applied `at the level of the SQL result set`. So, I assume it means that filtered entities are in the SQL result set, they are just never hydrated.

Comment: How would that work with limits? If I `setMaxResults(10)`, but I have 10,000 records for 100 different sites, the records for the siteId requested may not be in those 10 results... Also if there are millions of records, that would make for a lot of data to transfer from the database. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well, with all that in  mind, I suppose that filters might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: I wonder if there is anything else though? I may just have to manually manage filters on each query. I did some searching and haven't found any good solutions yet.

Comment: SQL filters will alter the sql query, so the other results will bever be hydrated. We are using this in production for the exact same use case you are describing and it works flawless.